# Scope of a variable in while loop (in C++)

Tags: c++, variables, while-loop, scope

I am writing a code in c++ in which the following has to be done- creating the number of varibles that the user wants. Here is the code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){

cout<<"how many variables do you want to enter"<<endl;  
int numVar; 
cin>>numVar;
int i=0;    
while(i<numVar){
    i++;        
    static int termi;
    // creates 'numVar' number of terms
    cout<<"enter term"<<i<<endl;        
    cin>>termi;
    //the user gives values of each term
}
// I want to cout all the terms here and do some calculations
return 0;
```

How can I use the variables created, outside the loop?
I have checked in -learncpp.com but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Comment: You can't create new variables with new names at run-time. Use containers instead.

Comment: Declare variables within the scope you need them.   If you want to access the variable in `main()` and outside the loop, define them within `main()` but outside the loop.   Declaring something `static` does not make its name accessible outside its enclosing scope.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable in `main` as `static` is pretty useless, just dont do it. Further you cannot "create" variables at runtime the way your are trying to. You want to use a `std::vector` instead and declare that before the loop. You could use something like this to read the values:

```
size_t num;
std::cin >> num;
std::vector<int> terms(num);
for (auto& e: terms) std::cin >> e;
```